# How to disable a button, except after checked RadioButton

Tags: android, button, radio-group

How to make a button unclickable, except after checking a radio button?

Comment: If you provide your code I can try to work a solution into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the button is called `myButton` try using

```
myButton.setEnabled(false);
```

Then you can add some type of listener to your radio button and in that listener add

```
myButton.setEnabled(true);
```

Also, you can check out the `android:clickable` attribute in xml.

Comment: No problem, hope it helps